# how we can retrieve the saved value from database to react-select dropdown in react?

Tags: python, reactjs, react-select

I am building a web application with React and Python (back end)

The application is having an identifier field and a couple of drop-downs to fill in. This application is having a feature to save the input data to a database with the identifier and but it is not necessary to fill all the input fields the first time.
When the user enters the identifier and clicks on the search button, it should retrieve the already entered values from the database to the input elements and allow the user to continue entering data from there.

This is my dropdown

```
import Select from "react-select"
```

```
const retDrop_current_value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('retDrop'))
```

```
const handleChange_RetDrop_file= (e) => {     console.log(e)    
console.log(JSON.stringify(e))     localStorage.setItem("retDrop",
JSON.stringify(e))     setselected_Retrofit(e.value);   }
```

```
<Select className='w-1/4' name='retDrop'           placeholder="Select"           value={retDrop_current_value} // set selected value           options={RetDrop_options}           onChange={handleChange_RetDrop_file} />
```

```
RetDrop_options=  [     { "value": "option1", "label": "option1" },    { "value": "option2", "label":"option2" } ]
```

the database will store the value as **option1 **and once it is retrieved, the drop-down should show the selected value as **option1**

I have an API to retrieve inputs from the database

```
async function retrieveInputs (event)
{

      event.preventDefault()
      const id = identifier 
      await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/getInputs/${id}`)
         .then(resp => resp.json())
         .then(data=>  setfromDatabase(data))
         .then(data=>getData(data))
    
    
         
    }
    console.log(fromDatabase.retDrop) // This is actually getting option1 from database
    localStorage.setItem('contractor_type',fromDatabase.retDrop) // this is not setting the value of dropdown
```